# Issues sorting by Date in a CRM report built using FetchXML

Tags: sorting, date, reporting-services, fetchxml

I am creating a few custom reports in CRM using FetchXML for the data source.  All of the reports are to be sorted by the CreatedOn attribute:

```
<order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
```

In the actual reports, I also have the both the Tablix (and Groups if applicable) sorted by CreatedOn Desc. This works but with one major drawback:  The dates are being sorted as if they were strings.

The dates are sorted starting with September them moving back to January:  9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 12, 11, 10 and finally 1.  September 9, 2015 is displayed before September 8, 2016. (string 9/9 > 9/8)

I applied expressions to convert the values to dates but that didn't work either:

```
=CDate(Fields!createdon.Value)
```

Any suggestions on getting the report to sort by actual dates and not as the strings?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your CDate is not able to convert the string.
As a test, try this:

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!createdon.Value),"yyyyMMdd")
```

If it looks the same, it is still being treated as a string.  You may have some invalid characters in the text that is preventing the conversion to date.  Is there any way you can classify the data type of the attribute in the XML?

Comment: When I didn't use the format, it added the time as well. I had done the formatting as well.  I just figured out an answer though...

Answer (score 0):

Since it was bringing back the field as a string, I added a new Calculated Field (CreatedOnDATE) to the data set.

I set the calculated field with the CDate:

```
=CDate(Fields!createdon.Value)
```

Then I simply changed the sort order to use the new CreatedOnDATE field and it worked like a charm.  It just took a good night sleep and a fresh perspective.